# Hot to deploy IIS with Nextjs Project

Tags: iis, next.js, iisnode

I want to deploy a Next.js project on IIS. I have installed IISNode and URL Rewriter. I have updated the web.config and server.js files. I edited the nodeProcessCommandLine section in the web.config, but I'm still getting the error shown in the screenshot. Can you assist me?

[image: localhost]

WebConig;

`
<system.webServer>

```
    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>

    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

<!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="node_modules"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
<iisnode node_env="production"/>
<!--
  You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
    * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
    * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
    * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

  See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
-->
<!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
```

`

No matter what I did, I couldn't fix it. Can you help me?

Comment: Try to add **<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />** in web.config. Change it to your path.

Comment: didn't work ..:/

Comment: You can refer to [Running Node.js Web Apps on IIS with HttpPlatformHandler](https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/). This tutorial is from Lex.

Comment: Updated my article with some Next.js specific steps, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs